# Select only 3 rows per user - SQL Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

These are the columns in my table

```
id (autogenerated)
created_user
created_date
post_text
```

This table has lot of values. I wanted to take latest 3 posts of every `created_user`

I am new to `SQL` and need help. I ran the below query in my Postgres database and it is not helpful

```sql
SELECT * FROM posts WHERE created_date IN
(SELECT MAX(created_date) FROM posts GROUP BY created_date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`row_number()` window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html) to create an ordered row count per user. After that you can easily filter by this value

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8590b509f58459603d9f3e7163f75cd9)

```
    SELECT
        *
    FROM (
        SELECT
            *,
            row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY created_user ORDER BY created_date DESC)
        FROM
            posts
    ) s
    WHERE row_number <= 3
```

- `PARTITION BY` groups the users
- `ORDER BY date DESC` orders the posts of each user into a descending order to get the most recent as `row_count == 1`, ...

Comment: added little explanation and demo fiddle